# Looking for an object traversal function

Tags: python

I have multiple needs to search a giant object tree - nested dicts and nested lists of arbitrary size. I also have a need to do a search & replace in some situations. I've come up with this simple function (py3):

```py
def _traverse_schema(schema: Union[list[Any], dict[Any]]):
  if isinstance(schema, list):
    for i, value in enumerate(schema):
      yield schema, i, value
      yield from _traverse_schema(value)
  if isinstance(schema, dict):
    for key, value in schema.items():
      yield schema, key, value
      yield from _traverse_schema(value)
```

This generator does all the recursion, so that when I use it I can just treat it as a single loop. The search is trivial, and the replace is also trivial since I yield the parent along with key and value:

```py
for section, key, value in _traverse_schema(schema):
  if key == "my search key" and value == "my search value":
    section[key] = "new value"
```

I'm really curious whether this traversal function exists in one of the standard libraries. I wasn't able to find anything like this in `itertools`. Does anyone know?

Comment: No, what you want does not exist in the standard library, given that values in dictionaries are not fixed to any one specific type (type hinting is not the same as type restriction), and thus no practical generalized solution may be done, thus such a feature would not be suitable for the standard library.  (As an aside, your iterator will not deal with self-referential values, i.e. a value that is itself or its (grand-)*parent).

Comment: @metatoaster Why would values in a dictionary need to be fixed to a specific type for it to be in a standard library? And good point about self referential -- my use case doesn't have it, but I think I could add a check for id() of a value via some wrapper

Comment: I specifically put it as "not fixed to any one specific type" to note that a generalized solution may not be practically done.  Not to mention that there are other iterable types - `sets` can be iterated and by their nature they are unordered (at least in older Python versions).  These are just some of the possible reasons why something like this is absent from the standard library for Python, and also how trivial this is that it is often better to leave it to the programmer to build upon the standard iterators to build a recursive walker/traverse function.